# Integrating inverse functions

Tags: calculus, integration, inverse

I'm trying to integrate the following:
$$\int_0^1 \left[\frac{c}{(1+c^{-1}(\tilde{b}))}\right]dc$$
If it helps
$$c(\tilde{b})=1-\frac{1}{(1-\tilde{b})\exp\left(\frac{2\tilde{b}}{(1-\tilde{b})}\right)}$$
where $\tilde{b}\in[0,1]$ and thus $c(\tilde{b})\in[0,1]$.
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I think numerical analysis is going to have to be the way to go on this. Thanks anyway!!